# Do struct instances get boxed when an extension method on a recursive generic interface is called?

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism, boxing

I have a 'recursive generic interface':

```
public interface MyInterface<T> where T : MyInterface<T>
{
    T DoSomething();
}
```

And I defined an extension method on it:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static T DoSomethingElse<T>(this T t)
        where T : MyInterface<T>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomethingElse was called.");
        return t.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

And then I implemented the interface in a struct:

```
public struct MyStruct : MyInterface<MyStruct>
{
    public MyStruct DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething was called.");
        return new MyStruct();
    }
}
```

And then I called the extension method in main:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyStruct x = new MyStruct();
        MyStruct y = x.DoSomethingElse();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The question: **When `DoSomethingElse` is called, does the object `MyStruct x` get boxed into `MyInterface`, or does the extension method operate directly on `x`?**

I have reasons to believe both:

- x is boxed: this would be the case if the interface wasn't recursive so that's possibly the case here, the extension method requires something of type `MyInterface` to operate on so the boxing happens
- x is not boxed: the parameter `T t` signifies the struct `MyStruct` directly, so it can be passed as is without boxing.

I tried really hard to think of a way to test this, but I can't find a way to capture the moment the struct is casted to the intreface type.

I apologize for the atrocious title but I couldn't word it any better, please feel free to edit it if you can describe the problem in more simple terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No boxing.

You can see that by putting your code into sharplab [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALANALiAlgGwD4AEAMACdBGAbgFgAodAZlwCZsBhbAb1Oxd0vSmwFkAKASkbNWwrgE8AynABOAVwDGcbGGwBebADsApgHduE6fLj9iJYSP2yF2UaqUA6ACIB7cU4C2muAAtE6gOYAosgAzprGQiwAvqTRJKQU2L5wmlIAZgCGcpp6AJLqyWmZmgA8ACoAfNjaXinZpdggufkpGVll5aRMpqz1zq4e3r5+4SSx8ex4ENR6AWDJ6sGITgudEWy4k9i9Lu6ePv5Boe08g8Fb2HB8a8LVteeNYnkFrSUVa11mrPgAnDwARH1doMDiFstp0mc5OlkMhNAATOx/PgmT4sdAAdgujh2A32w2Ra1iYzIlGCBisYkklkUD1ETxaRWKlPJcA6JA+X0ozOp2EBuKG/He1y+eF+AJxeyGVQh2ChMPhiIJ3U+GI0Oj0VMMI2ERKAA=). No `box` instructions. There's a constrained virtual call which *can* box in some cases, but not here.

If you cast the struct to its interface type, that will box:

```
MyInterface x = new MyStruct();
```

However, calling a generic method like this (whether or not the generic type parameter is constrained to the interface type), does not box. When you call `MyExtensions.DoSomethingElse<MyStruct>`, a new implementation of the method is emitted by the JIT, which specifically uses `MyStruct` - hence, no boxing is needed.

`MyExtensions.DoSomethingElse` does a [*constrained virtual call*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.constrained?view=netframework-4.7.2) to invoke the `DoSomething` method. This is used mainly when the compiler isn't sure whether the target will be a value or reference type at runtime, and it basically says "JIT, you figure this one out". Specifically:

> - If `thisType` is a value type and `thisType` implements `method` then `ptr` is passed unmodified as the 'this' pointer to a `call` `method` instruction, for the implementation of `method` by `thisType`.
> - If `thisType` is a value type and `thisType` does not implement `method` then `ptr` is dereferenced, boxed, and passed as the 'this' pointer to the `callvirt` `method` instruction.

Here, we hit the first case, and so no boxing happens. Had you called `t.GetHashCode()` or `t.GetType()`, then the JIT would emitted instructions to box `t`.